# WCF Routing Service with NetTcpBinding and certificates

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate

We want to add fail over ability to our WCF clients **at the client side** . The clients are communicating to a WCF service that is implemented over NetTcpBinding  with TransportWithMessageCredential security mode and the credential type is certificate.

Is it possible to use .Net 4.0 RoutingService without changing the real service security at all ?

The desired functionality from the router is just to pass the messages from the client to a backup service if the primary service is unavailable.